# PHPStorm не видит базу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

Через OpenServer запускаю PHPMyAdmin, создаю базу MySQL и таблицу, сохраняю.

В PHPStorm, в DataBase при попытке посмотреть какие базы есть ("TestConnection") возникает ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2241)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2265)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:868)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) (no stack trace).
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

С MySQL и средой PHPStorm только начинаю знакомиться.
Где и что нужно исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего поможет в строке подключения (там где написано URL) написать так: "jdbc:mysql://[хост]:[порт]/[бд]?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC". Хост, порт и бд укажите свои.

Comment: Да! Проблема решена!

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло. В PHPStorm в настройках базы данных, в графе URL, я вставила:

```
jdbc:mysql://НАШХОСТ:3306?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

После этого база данных все равно была не видна. Я обнаружила, что базу данных нужно сделать видимой, т.к. она у меня была скрыта по умолчанию. Решение есть:

В окне "Database" нужно правой кнопкой встать на название нашего ХОСТА и выбрать в меню:

```
Database tools 
-> Manage shown schemas 
   -> Отметить галочкой базу данных, которую хотим видеть.
```